# How can telnet socket be prevented from closing on encountering a blank line in middle of output?

Tags: python, telnet

I am using telnet script from python doc modules http://docs.python.org/library/telnetlib.html
The script works fine if the output has no blank lines.
But telnet Socket closes( script terminates) if it encounters a blank line.

Output is as follows:
line1
(blank line)
line2

```
import getpass  
import sys  
import telnetlib  

HOST = "localhost"  
user = raw_input("Enter your remote account: ")  
password = getpass.getpass()  

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)  

tn.read_until("login: ")  
tn.write(user + "\n")  
if password:  
    tn.read_until("Password: ")  
    tn.write(password + "\n")  

tn.write("ls\n")  
tn.write("exit\n")  

print tn.read_all()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. However, it would be helpful if you could post some code.

Comment: I tried your program but don't get that behavior.  Even with blank lines it continues to read forever.  Not many telnet servers around to test against...